# How to run wget from Windows 8.1 to reboot TP Link router

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, wget, router

I need to run the following line and I don't know how to. Help please.

Here is the code:

```
wget -q0 --user=User --password=Pass \ 
     http://192.168.1.1/userRpm/SysReboot.htm?Reboot=Reboot > /dev/null
```

OS: Windows 8.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need Wget for Windows, you can download it from here http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

open notepad and paste your code, save as "myscript.bat"

make sure it doesn't have .txt

put your "myscript.bat" in the same folder with wget.exe
now try it, it should work

Answer (score 0):

For a newer firmware version, U need to add referer and user-agent. Try this, work for me:

```
wget -qO- --user=admin --password=admin --referer http://192.168.0.1 --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" http://192.168.0.1/userRpm/SysRebootRpm.htm?Reboot=Reboot
```